# Show actual math source code in pdf

Tags: math-mode, pdftex

I have an almost blind student in my class who has a hard time reading many math symbols such as superscripts or subscripts ($M_1$, $K^3$). He has learnt to read the latex source code, which is easier for him to read. For this I need a second copy of all my documents in which the latex math source code is not compiled but instead produced as output in the pdf. For example, an exercise for him should read like this

Let g_1 and g_2 be two lines in \mathbb{R}^2.

instead of Let $g_1$ and $g_2$ be two lines in $\mathbb{R}^2$.

or

Show that \sum_{i=1}^n n = \frac{n(n+1)}{2}.

instead of Show that $\sum_{i=1}^n n = \frac{n(n+1)}{2}$.

Is there an easy way to tell TeX to simply ignore the math mode delimiters and instead just output the actual tex code from the file without producing dozens of error messages?

Comment: Side note: This is TeX code and "mathjax" has nothing to do with it. Mathjax is just using some of the LaTeX notations.

Comment: Maybe create a new command that either puts its argument in a math or verbatim environment?

Comment: Do you also use different math environments, e.g. from `amsmath`: `align`, `equation`, etc.? Than it would be a bit more complicated.

Comment: @dexteritas Sometimes yes, but the majority is inline math mode. I guess I could also switch to inline math completely if it turns out that it is too complicated for other environments.

Comment: Would the student be able to read the tex file?

Comment: @Teepeemm Good question, I am not sure

Answer (score 8):

Well with the (experimental!!!) math grabbing code that we develop it nearly works:

```
\DocumentMetadata{testphase=math}
\documentclass{article}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\math_processor:n
  {
    \texttt{\detokenize{#2}}\quad
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}

Show that $\sum_{i=1}^n n = \frac{n(n+1)}{2}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

One would only need to extend the code to allow to throw away the printed output.

Be aware that the grabbing code needs a very recent LaTeX (perhaps even latex-dev), it doesn't yet work with all math environments, and it quite probably has still bugs. Problems should be reported at https://github.com/latex3/tagging-project.

As an alternative you could try to tag your PDF. This will add the source code as alternative text:

```
\DocumentMetadata{testphase={phase-III,math}}
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

Show that $\sum_{i=1}^n n = \frac{n(n+1)}{2}$

\end{document}
```

Be aware that tagging works only with a restricted set of packages. Again problems (including feedback if this actually usable) can be reported at the github.

Comment: This looks already really promising. Unfortunately, LaTeX returns an error (! Undefined control sequence. l.1 \DocumentMetadata) for me. I guess that my LaTeX does not support this on Ubuntu :(

Comment: as I wrote: it requires a current LaTeX. The prepackaged tex systems are often outdated, if you want to use this code you will need a vanilla texlive installation.

Comment: @YukiJ I recommend vanilla Tex Live on Ubuntu anyway.  The packaged versions are almost guaranteed to be out of date, and installing Tex Live is easy.

Comment: Is there a possibility to activate and deactivate the tagging mode? For example, I don't need it in sentences. The sentence "Let $p$ be a prime number" is now converted to "Let p $p$ be a prime number". Is there a way to activate the tagging mode before some sentences and then turn it off again at the end of the sentence?

Comment: you can add some boolean around the `\texttt{\detokenize{#2}}\quad`, e.g. from etoolbox, and switch that on and off. And if you really use that: do not forget that it is experimental code and that it can change.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Thank you for your answer! This seems to work except for when I use math environments such as $$, displaymath, \[...\], align and the like. Then the processor throws several errors. Do you have any idea why that is or how to overcome it?

Comment: perhaps. But I won't start to discuss this in comments. Either ask a new question or if you think you found a bug report it at https://github.com/latex3/tagging-project (with an example and the log-file).

Answer (score 6):

For simple inline math you could define a command `\mymath` that has two different definitions for math and code mode.
The code is printed using the `listings` package.

#### Code

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{
    language = [LaTeX]{TeX},
    basicstyle=\small\ttfamily,
}

%\NewDocumentCommand{\mymath}{ m }{\ensuremath{#1}}% show math
\NewDocumentCommand{\mymath}{ v }{\lstinline|#1|}% show code

\begin{document}

\mymath{a^2 = b^2 + c^2}

\mymath{e = mc^2}

\mymath{\sum_{i=1}^n n = \frac{n(n+1)}{2}}

\end{document}
```

#### Result

[image]