# How to write the word sqrt in latex?

Tags: tables, table-of-contents, symbols

I'm trying to write the word sqrt, without the symbol appearing, like this: d = sqrt(sum(abs(x-y).^2));. But it doesn't let me.
My code is:

```
\begin{tabular}{l}
\changefont{
\text{d = norm(x-y);}
}\\
\changefont{
\text{d = sqrt(sum(abs(x-y).^2));}
}
\end{tabular}
```

The error is :
*Extra }, or forgotten $.
Missing $ inserted.
Extra }, or forgotten $.
Extra }, or forgotten $.*

Without this, my pdf works perfectly...

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please extend your code snippet to a compilable [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) and also tell what this code is supposed to look like in the end. What is the reason for the `\text` command? What does `\changefont` do? Note that you cannot use certain characters in text mode and TeX will complain with the above error if it encounters them. In this case the `^` character will break your code (you could try `\^{}`). Maybe what you want is to print things verbatim?

Comment: Welcome. // Please try the following to check, whether or not your posted code already is complete: A) copy your posted code into a fresh file in a new directory, B) compile it, C) add parts of code the errors indicate, D) repeat until it compiles, E) finally, replace your posted code by the version, we can copy nad compile now. Thank you

Comment: You can use [the techniques here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/553236) to create a command for it.

Comment: Kindly, and urgently, please turn your code snippet into code which compiles when copied. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/696390/how-to-write-the-word-sqrt-in-latex#comment1729189_696390 . Thank you

Comment: See [Show actual math source code in pdf](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/695930/123129). Here probably the `^` is the problem.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Show actual math source code in pdf](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/695930/show-actual-math-source-code-in-pdf)

Answer (score 1):

One possibility is to use the \verb environment.  This will produce exactly what occurs between the first + and the last +

```
\begin{tabular}{l}
   \verb+d = norm(x-y);+ \\
   \verb+d = sqrt(sum(abs(x-y).^2));+
 \end{tabular}
```

The above should produce

```
  d = norm(x-y);
  d = sqrt(sum(abs(x-y).^2));
```

Comment: Thank you. // Please DON'T mimick the OPs style of posting just a fragment. Please post only code, which compiles when copied. See my comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/696390/how-to-write-the-word-sqrt-in-latex#comment1729189_696390 .